# Samsung Galaxy S4 USB Screen Lock Error

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, storage, usb-connection-mode, macos

I have no idea what happened, but the last few times I have connected my Galaxy S4 to my Mac OSX to try and transfer music files (or any files for that matter) I get the message "**can't access device storage** If your device's screen is locked, disconnect its USB cable, unlock your screen, and then reconnect the USB cable."

Only problem is my screen is Not locked when I connected it in the first place. I have tried disconnecting, locking my screen, unlocking my screen, and then reconnecting but that doesn't work either…

Is there a way to fix this? All and any answers would be greatly appreciated.